# Finite series with sine in the denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

The given question:

> $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{13} \dfrac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{(k-1)\pi}{6}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{k\pi}{6}\right) }=?$$

By expanding the denominator using the $\sin (A+B)$ formula, I ended up with-
$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{13} \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \times \cos \frac{(k-1)\pi}{6} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \times \sin \frac{(k-1)\pi}{6} \right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \times \cos \frac{k\pi}{6} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\times \sin \frac{k\pi}{6}\right)}$$
$$=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{13} \dfrac{2}{\left(\cos \frac{(k-1)\pi}{6} + \sin \frac{(k-1)\pi}{6} \right)\left(\cos \frac{k\pi}{6} + \sin \frac{k\pi}{6}\right)}$$

We can expand the denominator and further simplify using the $\cos (A-B)$ and the $\sin (A+B)$ formulas, and after simplifying I have-

$$=\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{\sqrt 3}\sum_{k=1}^{13} \dfrac{1}{\sin(\frac{2k-1}{2}\frac{\pi}{6})}$$

The summation can be expanded as:

$$=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt 3} \left(\dfrac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{12}} + \dfrac{1}{\sin \frac{3\pi}{12}} + \dfrac{1}{\sin \frac{5\pi}{12}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sin \frac{25\pi}{12}}\right)$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217583/sum-m-16-frac1-sin-left-theta-leftm-1-right-cdot-frac-pi4?rq=1

Comment: Ah, I see what I should've done in the very first step.

Comment: See:https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/q-the-value-of-is-equal-sumk1131-sinpi-4-k-1pi-6sinpi-4-k-pi-6-is-equal-39519