# Solving $\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{1}{\sin(\theta+(m+1)\pi/4)\sin(\theta+m\pi/4)}=4\sqrt2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> For $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ find all solutions of the equation
> $$\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{1}{\sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}\right)}=4\sqrt2$$

I highly believe that this is a telescopic series but even after doing a lot of labour I couldn't find one. I tried using the method of differences but then I couldn't handle the expressions in the numerator.

I tried it by breaking it into $$-\frac{k}{\sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)}+\frac{k}{\sin\left(\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1217583/42969

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425966/finite-series-reciprocals-of-sines  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464031/find-the-sum-frac1-cos0-circ-cos1-circ-frac1-cos1-circ-cos2-cir

Comment: Unfriendly pseudo...

Comment: Have you attempted a numerical approach in order to know what the roots are likely to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating S would have been much faster if it were $\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}$

> For $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$.
> $$ S=\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{1}{\sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}\right)}=4\sqrt2$$

A key observation/trick to solving such kinds of problems include substituting the intimidating notations to simpler ones.

Put $\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}=t$

$$ S=\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{1}{\sin\left(t\right)\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

Multiplying and dividing with $sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

$$ S=\sqrt2\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{sin\frac{\pi}{4}}{\sin\left(t\right)\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

Now, $\frac{\pi}{4}=t+\frac{\pi}{4}-t=t-\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$....(1)

Substituting (1) above,

$$ S=\sqrt2\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{sin\left(t-\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)}{\sin\left(t\right)\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

using $sin(a-b)=sin(a)cos(b)-cos(a)sin(b)$

$$ S=\sqrt2\sum_{m=1}^{11}\frac{sin(t)cos\left(\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)-cos(t)sin\left(\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)}{\sin\left(t\right)\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

$$ S=\sqrt2\sum_{m=1}^{11} cot\left({t-\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)-cot(t)$$

Putting back $\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}=t$

$$ S=\sqrt2\sum_{m=1}^{11} cot\left({\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}}\right)-cot\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)$$

On telescoping we get,

$$S=\sqrt 2 \left[cot(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})-cot(\theta+3\pi)\right]=4\sqrt2$$

$$\left[cot(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})-cot(\theta+3\pi)\right]=4$$

I think you can solve from here for $\theta$